# how to validate existing records with new records in frontend using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, sql-server

**Requirement:**

Should add new holiday into holiday table and check into the database.If there is no holiday in database, then it should be added. Else it should show an alert, holiday already exists.
I have been able to Successfully add holidays, but duplicate records are also able to add. 
How to validate this in front end using Jquery/Javascript.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Please put your working code here so any one can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make an ajax call to server every time you add an holiday and pass the entered holiday as a parameter to this ajax call, and then on server check if the received parameter(holiday) already exists in DB , return true or false in case of if record exists or not. In the ajax call success function check the response from server , if its "true" e.g record exists in DB , then make an alert.